# Handling user input in dagster

Tags: python, input, dagster

I am new to dagster and I am trying to understand how user inputs are handled by it. I am testing this out with the following piece of code:

```
from dagster import job, op


@op
def input_string():
    ret = input('Enter string')
    print(ret)


@job
def my_job():
    input_string()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_job.execute_in_process()
```

I then run the following in console:

```
dagit -f test.py
```

When I finally "Launch Run" however, I don't get an opportunity to enter input, and instead get an EOFError with the following info:

> dagster.core.errors.DagsterExecutionStepExecutionError: Error occurred
> while executing op "input_string":   File
> "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\execution\plan\execute_plan.py",
> line 232, in dagster_event_sequence_for_step
> for step_event in check.generator(step_events):   File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\execution\plan\execute_step.py",
> line 354, in core_dagster_event_sequence_for_step
> for user_event in check.generator(   File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\execution\plan\execute_step.py",
> line 70, in _step_output_error_checked_user_event_sequence
> for user_event in user_event_sequence:   File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\execution\plan\compute.py",
> line 170, in execute_core_compute
> for step_output in *yield_compute_results(step_context, inputs, compute_fn):   File
> "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\execution\plan\compute.py",
> line 138, in *yield_compute_results
> for event in iterate_with_context(   File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dagster\utils_*init**.py",
> line 403, in iterate_with_context
> return   File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in **exit**
> self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)   File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\execution\plan\utils.py",
> line 73, in solid_execution_error_boundary
> raise error_cls( The above exception was caused by the following exception: EOFError: EOF when reading a line   File
> "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\execution\plan\utils.py",
> line 47, in solid_execution_error_boundary
> yield   File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dagster\utils_*init**.py",
> line 401, in iterate_with_context
> next_output = next(iterator)   File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\execution\plan\compute_generator.py",
> line 65, in _coerce_solid_compute_fn_to_iterator
> result = fn(context, **kwargs) if context_arg_provided else fn(**kwargs)   File "test.py", line 14, in input_string
> ret = input('Enter string')

How can I get this to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ops are configured using a [config schema](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/ops#op-configuration). This allows you to provide configuration via the [Dagit Launchpad](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/ops#op-configuration)

In your case you'd want to remove the `input` call from your `@op` code. You would then retrieve the input from the config object provided to your op using the `context.op_config` dictionary, something like this:

```py
@op(config_schema={'input1': str})
def input_string(context):
    ret = context.op_config['input1']
    print(ret)

@job
def my_job():
    input_string()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_job.execute_in_process()
```

edit: To get your input to print in the Dagster job console use the built-in [Dagster logger](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/logging/loggers#using-a-logger) like this:

```py
@op(config_schema={'input1': str})
def input_string(context):
    ret = context.op_config['input1']
    context.log.info(ret)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I tweaked the code to define a config_schema, and hardcoded input using both a YAML document in Dagit and a run_config inside the execute_in_process() method. I noticed that if I insist on using input(), which I can inside a run_config, Dagit skips this step and passes an empty string, whereas Python API stops and asks for user input (and prints it to console if I have a print statement). I conclude that Dagster is not really meant to work with user inputs from console, but rather inputs from config documents. As a follow-up: how can I feed input from a database?

Comment: @cpowr - that's correct, interaction with dagster is mostly meant to occur through the Launchpad UI or the GraphQL interface, using run_configs which are used to configure the ops and resources in a job. You wouldn't directly feed inputs from a database - you could either have a separate service read data from your database and submit runs via the GraphQL interface, or have an op at the beginning of a job retrieve your inputs from a database and then feed them to downstream ops.